# How to list posts based off of number of posts with Jekyll and Liquid?

Tags: list, post, numbers, jekyll, liquid

I have tried to figure this out and have been unable to reach a happy conclusion.

Basically, what I want to do is detect the number of posts on my Jekyll site, and list the posts based off of that number. For example, if there is only one post, I want to list that post, full-length, and with all of the formatting. If there are two posts, I want to list both as snippets, and without the HTML formatting. If there are three, the same as with two posts. If there are more than three, I want to do the same as with two and three posts, but with a "view all posts" link because I want three at max to be listed on the homepage, but do not want a "view all posts" link if there are not more than three posts.

*Before listing my current code, I would like to note that I have tried using `paginator.total_posts` (I use jekyll-paginate on my site) and that listed nothing.*

Here is my code at the moment:

```
{% if site.posts | size == 1 %}
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    {{ first post coding, full-length }}      
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% if site.posts | size == 2 %}
  {% for post in site.posts limit:1 %}
    {{ first post coding, snippet }}    
  {% endfor %}
  {% for post in site.posts limit:1 offset:1 %}
    {{ second post coding, snippet }}   
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% if site.posts | size == 3 %}
  {% for post in site.posts limit:1 %}
    {{ first post coding, snippet }}    
  {% endfor %}
  {% for post in site.posts limit:1 offset:1 %}
    {{ second post coding, snippet }}   
  {% endfor %}
  {% for post in site.posts limit:1 offset:2 %}
    {{ third post coding, snippet }}    
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% if site.posts | size > 3 %}
  {% for post in site.posts limit:1 %}
    {{ first post coding, snippet }}    
  {% endfor %}
  {% for post in site.posts limit:1 offset:1 %}
    {{ second post coding, snippet }}   
  {% endfor %}
  {% for post in site.posts limit:1 offset:2 %}
    {{ third post coding, snippet }}    
  {% endfor %}
  {{ "view all posts" link coding }}
{% endif %}
```

Problem is that my page is outputting with all of the `{% if %}` statements; it is not selecting just one, the one for the number that `{{ site.posts | size }}` outputs. This baffles me, because when I put `{{ site.posts | size }}` in my code, it lists the proper number in every case.

I have tried changing `==` to `contains` and even `:`, but I still get the same result.

I am not sure where to go from here, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix tests and filters. Try the following:

```
{% assign post_count=site.posts | size %}
{% if post_count == 1 %}
...
```

Note that with arrays, you can use the size attribute instead of a filter:

```
{% if site.posts.size == 1 %}
...
```

Comment: I tried `{% if site.posts.size == 1 %}` with no success, but your other suggestion works perfectly. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I could have sworn I tried `{% if site.posts.size == 1 %}` before posting the question, but I tried it again just now and it works exactly the same as the other option does. Weird. I apologize! :)

Comment: I didn't test myself before answering, I should do it anyway :)